# Place a photo in the correct position (html)

Tags: position, photo

Hi i have created this html code for add photos on my site , the photo with my computer is seen in the correct posizone, but when when I see my picture on the computer of my friend I find the picture in a different location, how can I fix this problem ?

```html
<img src="https://s27.postimg.org/8gj6vh1ur/a1_android.png"  style="position: absolute; z-index: -10; width: auto; height: 50%; top: 785px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 24px" />
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Although your snipet is too incomplete to provide any sort of answer I will point out that "width: auto; height: 50%;" make your picture's dimensions variable based on the monitor's resolution and operating system (retina display, scaling etc).